# Unpopular  "elementary" theorems/identities to impress an audience of mathematicians.

Tags: big-list, gm.general-mathematics

This question grew out of my recent job interview. Since the interviewers were math professors, I had a hard time searching for interesting elementary theorems in case I got asked for one.
I thought topics such as the Banach-Tarski paradox, Godel's theorems, the Mandelbrot set, the Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem, etc were well-known and wouldn't do the job. However, after a cursory search, I found some to my taste:

1.<s>[Marden's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marden%2527s_theorem) (or  [here](http://www.maa.org/joma/Volume8/Kalman/index.html))(It is not Marsden.)</s> [Gauss–Lucas theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss-Lucas_theorem)

2.The identity $\int_{0}^1 \frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+ x^4} dx = \frac{22}{7}- \pi$

So, my  question here is an invitation to expand the list (of theorems that would get an interviewee accepted).

To recap, my criteria for selection are

1. Not widely known,
2. Elementary- understandable to a first year grad student, and
3. Interesting-i.e. MOtizens, assuming they are the audience, will be delighted to have come across it.

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you expect to be asked to state interesting elementary theorems at your job interview? It's not like a thesis defense. You tell them what you know, not what they would like you to know.

Comment: I guess I assumed it was an interview for a faculty position, but maybe it was some other kind of job?

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong, but I think your first example is extremely well-known; it's in Alfohrs, for example.

Comment: I am a student there and the faculty wanted to recruit tutors for freshmen/sophomores. But their selection criteria was not only ability to do the tutoring but they also wanted to know whether the applicant wants to continue a career in Mathematics, how he can entice/encourage his juniors to go on studying Math, what Math field he delights in, etc. 



Comment: Have to agree with Spiro; it seems like an odd thing to prepare for a job interview, unless you had some reason to believe you'd be asked this. I would think a more reasonable question along these lines is: what are some nice *applications* of elementary theorems that you can explain to undergraduates? (Example I have in mind is coin-flipping protocols that involve the structure of the product of two finite fields.) Just citing results however seems kinda dull... 


Comment: (Sorry, Elohemahab -- I didn't see your reply before I posted.) 

Comment: @ Litt, sorry, edited.

Comment: Okay, in that case it makes sense. But I would remove the "interview" tag because I think it's implicit that "interview" refers to interviews for tenure-track academic jobs.

Comment: Even granting the somewhat strange motivation of this question: isn't it self-defeating?  Whatever gets posted here will become much more widely known.  Moreover, I find it somehow dishonest to get examples of one's mathematical knowledge and enthusiasm from others on the internet.  I am voting to close.

Comment: @Spiro, this tag has no precedent. But I will change it to "General-Math".

Comment: It is not clear to me what really this list will achieve. Also, by "unpopular" you mean "not well-known" rather than "not popular." The former would have been a more interesting list!

Comment: I agree with Pete but could not find a good way to say it.  It seems to me that in light of your interview you should be trying to figure out how to _become a better candidate_ rather than finding ways to trick the hiring committee, or whatever, into thinking you are a better candidate than you are?

Comment: @Pete. (1)I have already been interviewed. What baffles me is what I could have presented  had I time to search for more. (2) I have not even implicitly asked for somebody's motivation for being a mathematician. I am sorry for the ambiguity my comment above created.

Comment: @Qiaochu, all candidates were students on good standing in the department( with little differences in CGPA.). The only option for the department, I suppose, was to test their 'beyond-class' knowledge of Mathematics.  

Comment: @Elohemahab, if I were conducting the interview and asked that question (I doubt I would...) the idea would be to find out what maths you *know*, not wat you *searched* for. I am pretty sure I could tell the difference between the two with a few more questions!

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez, isn't math I searched for and understood, math I know? They do not know whether you searched for it or you knew it long ago. It seems that this discussion forces other to think that I am summoning help in order to cheat interviewers, which is not what I am doing. To be honest, they did not ask any such thing. But in my preparation, I hypothesized that such questions were to be asked. 

Comment: +1 simply for pointing out Marden's theorem. 

Answer (score 6):

The AM-GM inequality is implied by an identity.

For a function $f=f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n):\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ let $Pf(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ denote the sum of $f$ over the $n!$ quantities that result from all possible $n!$ permutations of the $x_i$. Then
$$\frac{x_1^n+x_2^n+\dots+x_n^n}{n}-x_1x_2\dots x_n=\frac{1}{2\ n!}(\phi_1+\phi_2+
\dots \phi_n),$$
where
$$\phi_k=P[(x_1^{n-k}-x_2^{n-k})(x_1-x_2)x_3x_4\dots x_{k+1}]$$
$$=P[(x_1-x_2)^2(x_1^{n-k-1}+\dots x_2^{n-k-1})x_3x_4\dots x_{k+1}]\geq0.$$
The proof dates back to Hurwitz.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks. I am checking for $n= 2, 3,\ldots$.

Comment: Am I hallucinating here or is anyone else reminded of the usual constructions of contracting homotopies?

Comment: What do you mean Darij?

Comment: OK, I was hallucinating. In homological algebra there is no need to symmetrize for obtaining telescoping sums.